# Can't print } on Visual Studio 2017 on Italian keyboard

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+]</kbd> on an Italian keyboard to add a closed curly brace, Visual Studio selects a block of my code instead of printing it. 
I have already tried to reset the keyboard mapping on Visual Studio but to no avail.

Other programs works without problems. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: To check what shortcut is hijacking a keypress you can use the method I described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/51921583

Comment: You can also type the curly braces by pressing SHIFT + ALT GR + braces.

Comment: @Banex they are telling me that also `SHIFT + ALT GR + {` is affected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a *new feature* appeared in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.0.
It is called `ExpandSelectionToContainingBlock` and it is mapped to the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+]</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+ALT+SHIFT++</kbd> (For VS in Italian)

But this mapping has removed the ability, from some keyboards without the key for the closing brace (like the Italian one), to press those keys and get the, indispensable for many programming languages, close curly brace.

As far as I know there are two workarounds

1. Go to *Tools* menu and select *Customize*
2. Press the *Keyboard* button
3. Search for *Edit.ExpandSelectionToContainingBlock*
4. Press *Remove*

or just use the numeric keypad and press

<kbd>ALT+0125</kbd>

For Italian readers with the Italian version of VS, the search above at point 3 should be for *Modifica.Espandiselezioneabloccocontenitore*. I don't know if other languages are affected by this 'translation vice' but it is a thing to be aware of.

The problem has already been reported to MS (Thanks Albireo)

**EDIT:** It seems that they have [fixed the problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289516/cannot-type-close-brace.html), in version 18.5.2 there is anything assigned to the shortcut. But I am not sure if this is an effect of my previous action or if this (no shortcut) is the real default now.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!

Comment: The problem has already been reported in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289516/cannot-type-close-brace.html (and many other closed as duplicates), the answer given is the same as yours.

Comment: Regarding the keys combination: on an Italian keyboard the correct combination is `SHIFT`, `CTRL`, `ALT` and `+`, *not* `]`. The `]` is not available on the keyboard without modifiers and is obtained by using `CTRL`, `ALT` and `+`. You can also see the culprit shortcut in the screenshot in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51927127 Source: have an Italian keyboard.

Comment: @Albireo Interesting, me too, but Visual Studio is the English version and the shortcut is linked to the closing square bracket. Indeed the + and the ] are in the same physical key on my Microsoft Comfort Keyboard 5000

Comment: @jessehouwing why did you close this as duplicate and not the other one?

Comment: I started closing against that one answer and then started searching for other questions. If I had stumbled upon this one first I'd likely had closed them into this one. When I noticed this was older and had more votes I had already closed other questions against the other question. Flip of a coin type situation.