# Recent Visual Studio update introduced shortcut used to create closing curly brace on my keyboard: how to find offending command?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

A recent update to Visual Studio has introduced a new or updated shortcut key that on my non-English keyboard allowed me to create closing curly braces (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>). This shortcut still works as expected outside of VS (e.g. in notepad) but in VS it is now associated to some text selection command (like select text from the cursor position to the bottom of the file).

How can I find the offending shortcut key command among the hundreds in VS? I remembered the existence of a VS add-in that allowed printing out all currently set shortcut keys to attempt generating a list I could quickly search through but I failed at finding it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/51909462

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been driving me crazy for the last week. I tried to disable ReSharper, to reset the keybindings, to repair Visual Studio, all to no avail, I haven't been able to type closing curly braces since then. It never occurred to me that a new shortcut could have been introduced hijacking the keypress until reading your question.

To check if there's a rogue shortcut hijacking your keypresses, open the keyboard options screen using the *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Keyboard* menus and click inside the "Press shortcut keys" field (it doesn't matter which command is selected):

[image]

Then press the affected keys combination, the combination will appear in the "Press shortcut keys" field and the associated commands - if any is - will be listed in the "Shortcut currently used by" drop-down:

[image]

To remove the shortcuts you need to search for **every** entry listed in the drop-down by typing the command name in the "Show command containing" field, selecting the entry in the filtered list, and removing **every** entry listed in the "Shortcuts for the selected commands" drop-down by clicking the "Remove" button.

[image]

Comment: After the keybinding has been applied through the new feature introduction, you may need to reset the keybinding for this binding to be undone. Unless you manually remove the command binding.